# How to create a simple JSON object using an external reference for the KEY value?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a very simple school project in which I play around with a very simple JSON API that looks like this:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "488 GT3",
    "engine": "3900cc Twin Turbo",
    "brand": "FERRARI",
    "year": "2016",
    "horsePower": "493",
    "maxSpeed": "330",
    "races": {
      "Road Atlanta": true,
      "Sebring International Raceway": false
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "718 Cayman GTS4",
    "engine": "4000cc",
    "brand": "PORSCHE",
    "year": "2020",
    "horsePower": "400",
    "maxSpeed": "293",
    "races": {
      "Long Beach street circuit": true,
      "Canadian Tire Motorsport Park": false
    }
  }
]
```

I am using React with Node.js and Express framework. I can easily create very simple instances of a car looking like the above, using a simple  template.
What I'm struggling to do is to populate the nested JSON object which is called 'races'. I can easily create a car populating all the other information, but I am stuck at some point for the nested 'races' JSON object.

In my express router, here is what I have done so far for the 'POST' method to create cars:

```
app.post('/cars', (req, res)=> {
    let newCar ={}
    newCar.id = req.body.id,
    tempRace = req.body.race,
    newCar.name = req.body.name,
    newCar.engine = req.body.engine,
    newCar.brand = req.body.brand,
    newCar.year = req.body.year,
    newCar.horsePower = req.body.horsePower,
    newCar.maxSpeed = req.body.maxSpeed,
    newCar.races = { ...newCar.race, /* I NEED THE VALUE OF req.body.races IN THERE */ }
    cars.push(newCar)

    res.status(200).json(cars)
})
```

So the real issue here is that I need to inject the value of req.body.race into the nested object called races, and I can't pass on that key value inside the object.

i consoled out a few things as below :

```
app.post('/cars', (req, res)=> {
    
    console.log(req.body),

    let newCar ={}
    newCar.races = req.body.race
    newCar.id = req.body.id,
    newCar.name = req.body.name,
    newCar.engine = req.body.engine,
    newCar.brand = req.body.brand,
    newCar.year = req.body.year,
    newCar.horsePower = req.body.horsePower,
    newCar.maxSpeed = req.body.maxSpeed,

    cars.push(newCar)
    res.status(200).json(cars)

    console.log(JSON.stringify(cars))
})
```

and both console.logs show that off course the race has been added to the 'RACES' property, but my concern is that i don't know how to create a 'races' object and then injecting my race in it.

so here are both my console logs :
console.log(req.body) returns this result

```
{
  id: 21,
  name: 'lm,',
  brand: 'lm,',
  engine: 'lm,',
  year: 'lm,',
  horsePower: 'lm,',
  maxSpeed: 'lm,',
  race: 'Autodromo Hermanos Rodriguez'
}
```

and console.log(JSON.stringify(cars)) returns all of my Api :

```
}
[{"id":1,"name":"488 GT3","engine":"3900cc Twin Turbo","brand":"FERRARI","year":"2016","horsePower":"493","maxSpeed":"330","races":{"Road Atlanta":true,"Sebring International Raceway":false}},{"id":2,"name":"718 Cayman GTS4","engine":"4000cc","brand":"PORSCHE","year":"2020","horsePower":"400","maxSpeed":"293","races":{"Long Beach street circuit":true,"Canadian Tire Motorsport Park":false}},{"id":4,"name":"M8 GTE","engine":"3981cc V8 Twin Turbo","brand":"BMW","year":"2019","horsePower":"567","maxSpeed":"306","races":{"Silverstone Circuit":true,"Long Beach street circuit":false}},{"id":3,"name":"AMG GT4","engine":"3982cc V8 Twin Turbo","brand":"MERCEDES","year":"2019","horsePower":"510","maxSpeed":"250","races":{"Le Castellet":true,"Fuji Speedway":false}},{"id":5,"name":"Huracan Super Trofeo","engine":"5200cc V10","brand":"LAMBORGHINI","year":"2017","horsePower":"620","maxSpeed":"327","races":{"Indianapolis Raceway Park":true,"Le Castellet":true,"Road Atlanta":true,"Fuji Speedway":true}},{"races":"Daytona International Speedway","id":1245,"name":"twingo","engine":"2000","brand":"RENAULT","year":"2013","horsePower":"","maxSpeed":""},{"races":"Autodromo Hermanos Rodriguez","id":21,"name":"lm,","engine":"lm,","brand":"lm,","year":"lm,","horsePower":"lm,","maxSpeed":"lm,"}]
```

i am not very sure to know where i need to declare 'races' as a JSON object ? probably at the Form level in my carForm.jsx file ?

Comment: What does `req.body.race` look like? What does your payload in general look like (i.e. req.body). I would more expect you to send a car object with a `races` object instead of a `race` object, but I might be misunderstanding the flow. If you sent a car object with a `races` property, you could just do `newCar.races = req.body.races`.

Answer (score 0):

alright i have solved my own problem.

i only needed to declare the object containing my race with this syntax :

```
newCar.races = {[req.body.race] : true}
```

instead of doing the way i did before wich only declares a property

```
newCar.races = req.body.race
```